# onPaste e.preventDefault Fail on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, summernote

I have a problem with contenteditable in summernote.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkLYvV

**Current Behaviour:** Safari/Firefox - When paste image, it just show Pasting Not ALLowed, but on Chrome, it shows Pasting Not Allow together with the image paste.

**Expected Behaviour:** Disable pasting of image entirely.

This seems to be pointed to a issue with on paste event in Chrome.

I want to prevent pasting of image, so I've added in e.preventDefault but chrome still paste the image. Below are my codes and some of my console.log to debug the behavior. Any other ways to prevent chrome from pasting?

```
 $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 300,
        minHeight: 300,
        toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['insert',['link','picture']]

        ],


        callbacks : {

            onPaste: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('pasting'); // Chrome shows This

                var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text'); //This actually removes the image because image is not text.



        console.log(bufferText); //Chrome Shows Empty
        console.log(typeof bufferText); //Chrome Shows String
        console.log(bufferText.length); //Chrome Shows 0
        if (bufferText.length == 0) {
            console.log ('in if loop'); //Chrome Shows this in Console

            document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Paste Not Allowed'); //Chrome wrote "Paste Not Allowed" in contenteditable but the image still get pasted.
            return false;
        }
                if (!bufferText)
                    return true;

                document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
            }

        }


    });
```

**Update: Throw new error to preventDefault.**

Currently this is what i've done temporarily. If only someone can suggest a better way than to throw a error to stop default action.

It appears that this security settings / chrome browser, i have to add something to get the bufferText

```
var bufferText = ((ne.originalEvent || ne).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/plain') || null;

        if (bufferText == null) {
            throw new Error("Cannot Paste Image");

        }
```

By throwing the new error i am able to stop the posting of the image but i can allow all other forms of text.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of you callback `onPaste`, put a `return false;` it should work. That's the way I use instead of `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: e.preventDefault() + e.stopPropagation() + return false, and it's still pasting on my contenteditable DIV